# can't click on a button (element is not visible) c# webdriver

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on a button, but I get "element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with", how can I fix this?
I tried using commands like:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnSave")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath(".//*[@id='btnSave']")).Click();
```

sorry I did not understand how to use html properly in comments(just deleted all the <>)

```
button id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="save" data-target="#" name="command"

i aria-hidden="true" data-icon="Z" /i
span class="title" Saugoti /span
/button
```

Comment: Are you sure the element is actually visible? Are there any other elements having the same id? Thanks.

Comment: I just found out that there is a hidden element with the same id, so how do I deal with this situation?

Answer (score 0):

> I just found out that there is a hidden element with the same id, so how do I deal with this situation?

This means that you've located the "Save" button that is invisible.

You should improve your location strategy. For instance, look for the button inside a specific form:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("form#myform button#btnSave")).Click();
```

Or, just get all the buttons and choose the one by index:

```
driver.FindElements(By.Id("btnSave"))[1].Click();
```

Comment: This did not work and I found out that when I open the page, click works fine, but when I open some pop up window in that page and try to click after, then webdriver looses focus or something and click does not work anymore

Comment: @ŽygimantasDirma what do you mean by does not work - any errors? Are you seeing any iframes on the page?

Comment: I mean that click works fine, but when I open and close pop up window on that page, same click command does not work because "element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with". There is no iframes

Comment: that pop up is some kind of modal window